# Would someone please describe or explain airship or zeppelin avionics packages

Tags: flight-controls, avionics, radar

[image: Zeppelin Avionics]

I'm hoping to learn more about this avionics pictue, with a plan to redesign the user interface. Would someone be willing to share other pictures, along with descriptions of each data point?

Comment: Some reference?

Comment: I've seen these on games/simulations (Flightgear has a Zeppelin NT available and its panels look similar to that.)  The Pitch figures (LH RH and aft) are for the three propellors, though I can't say whether they are blade pitch or the angle of the nacelles themselves.  The "Ballonet" bits are for adjusting the pitch/balance by pumping air into front or rear airbags, as well as controlling the overall gas pressure.  The % may be a subjective "fill level".